# Can outdated versions of answers be removed?

Tags: support, hyperlinks

In [this question](https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/questions/139843/how-to-oxidise-iron-in-spinach-to-ironiii/139851#139851) I initially answered with a Google link, and drew a comment asking me to remove the link.  I edited the answer with a different link to the reference, but the previous versions remain accessible and the old link is still there.  Is there any way to remove the content now that it is not in the most updated version of the answer?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I assume you want to remove the revision in the edit history; in that case: no.<sup>*</sup>

In any case, one would have to go through more than a couple of clicks, or copying and pasting these Google links, to actually use them. I'd assume that the few people who do that, do know exactly what they are doing. I'm positive that this is not really an issue. As long as the final post has the correct links, 99%+ people should be safe.

### How to avoid tracking links?

When you research support/sources for your answer or question, always follow through to the actual landing page of the content. From the address field of your browser, you should be able to copy the link into your post. **Never copy the link from the search results page.** Always try to find a permalink; e.g. on SE this is available through the *share* button below the post.

Sometimes, you can use *incognito mode* to disable this tracking; **sometimes!**

I personally prefer not using any links to pdf (or other sources) directly without telling/ marking them, and I appreciate if others do that, too.

If it is an official publication, e.g. a journal article, it likely has a doi. You can (and should) securely link through http://doi.org. I recommend this wonderful little user script: [CitationHelperForSE](https://github.com/GaurangTandon/CitationHelperForSE).

---

<sup>*</sup> There are possibilities to remove sensitive information permanently (redacting posts), but this sort does not qualify, and it's not the easiest of processes.

Comment: This should also be relevant: [FAQ: How should I use external sources on Chemistry Stack Exchange?](https://chemistry.meta.stackexchange.com/q/4294/4945)